# How to deploy user packages to shared folder "repo"?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, tooling

I'm new to the Python project tooling and currently finding my ways around it. I'd like to standardize a set of Python projects and to that end I'm doing the following:

1. Using [`pyscaffold`](https://github.com/pyscaffold/pyscaffold) to generate project templates i.e. `conda install pyscaffold && putup my_project`.
2. Testing using `python setup.py test`
3. Build source dist using `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`

Provided that I have set the `PYTHONPATH` to a shared drive `/dev/shared/dist/Lib/site-packages/` and where `Lib/site-packages/` is the suffix needed by Python AFAIK. How can I have the standardized projects built to output distributions either binary or source to that folder so that `pip install my_project` or for that matter building dependent projects will pick my packages from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-t` (target) flag to install to a folder. So for instance:

```sh
mkdir target_folder
TARGET=target_folder

python -m pip install -t $TARGET requests
```

or using a wheel/dist that you've generated:

```sh
python -m pip install -t $TARGET my_package.tar.gz
```

This should also work for a mounted directory

Comment: Thank you! will it work too for dependant projects e.g. `my_project2` lists `my_project` as dependency?

Comment: That's a good question, if the dependencies live on a `pip` server that is either Pypi or a pip server that you own, it should work. If they are packaged projects that live locally on your machine, I'm not so sure